# Powershell how to sum time

Tags: powershell

I am running a Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics script to pull the OverallDuration for each PST imported. I am trying to then sum them using the measure-object -sum but keep getting "measure : Input object "00:03:00.4321755" is not numeric." I assume I have to format the output?

```
$mbxreqs = Get-MailboxImportRequest -BatchName csr2 | where {$_.status -eq "Completed"}

    $TimeCollection =@()
    foreach ($mbx in $mbxreqs) {
    $mbxstat = Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics -Identity $mbx.RequestGuid | Select-Object @{L="MigTime";E={$_.OverallDuration}}

    $result = New-Object psobject
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MigTime" -Value $mbxstat.migtime
    $TimeCollection += $result
    }

    ($TimeCollection | measure -property migtime -sum).sum
```

Comment: Looking at the return from that cmdlet, what you get is an Enhanced Timespan object, which has addition operators, so you could also do `$TotalDuration = [timespan]::Zero;$TimeCollection|ForEach{$TotalDuration = $TotalDuration + $_.migtime};$TotalDuration`. That would create a timespan of 0, then loop through all the other timespans and add them to it, leaving you with a timespan for the whole thing that you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

```
($TimeCollection | select -exp migtime | measure -prop TotalMilliseconds -sum).sum;
```

## Details

**Minimal Reproduction**

This recreates your scenario:

```
$timespan1 = New-TimeSpan $(Get-Date) $(Get-Date -month 12 -day 31 -year 2017);
$result1 = New-Object psobject;                                                   
$result1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MigTime" -Value $timespan1;

$timespan2 = New-TimeSpan $(Get-Date) $(Get-Date -month 12 -day 31 -year 2017);
$result2 = New-Object psobject;    
$result2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MigTime" -Value $timespan2;

$TimeCollection = @( $result1, $result2 );

($TimeCollection | measure -property migtime -sum).sum;
```

The same error occurs:

> measure : Input object "148.00:00:00.0010041" is not numeric.

**Solution**

Sum of duration in milliseconds:

```
$TimeCollection `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty migtime `
    | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -sum;
```

Sum of durations in days:

```
$TimeCollection `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty migtime `
    | Measure-Object -Property TotalDays -sum;
```

In one line with aliases:

```
($TimeCollection | select -exp migtime | measure -prop TotalMilliseconds -sum).sum;
```

**Explanation**

The error occurred because of trying to run an arithmetic operation on an object that does not support arithmetic operations. The solution was to expand the object and run the arithmetic operation on one of its numeric properties.